# (PPC64le) node-gyp rebuild of a module that links to protobuf fails with "lacks nop, can't restore toc; recompile with -fPIC"

Tags: c++, linux, node.js, node-gyp

First time poster, long time fan...

I'm trying to rebuild a node module for ppc64le (little endian) on RHEL 7.1 and getting the following output which is perplexing. I've done the same steps on an x64 vm, and everything compiled fine.

Part of the output is below, even though it says to compile with -fPIC, that option is already in the g++ command emmitted, as shown in the output, so I don't know what to make of this error.

And even though it's looking in a linux-x64 directory for the static protobuf library:  ../sdk/protobuf/2.5.0/linux-x64/libprotobuf.a

I replaced the contents of that directory with libraries compiled for ppc64le from the protobuf-static-2.5.0-7.el7.ppc64le rpm from the epel repo. So the libs should be ok and they are the same version as expected by the node module

so what does this error mean? and how can I get past it? The same steps that I'm using worked fine in linux-x64. The main difference I can think of is that I had to bring in some static libs (protobuf.a) for ppc64le that I got from the protobuf-static-2.5.0-7.el7.ppc64le package. These get linked into the node module that I'm gyp'ng. Below is the output from 'node-gyp rebuild --verbose'

Thanks in advance!

```
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
gyp verb command build []
gyp verb build type Release
gyp verb architecture ppc64
gyp verb node dev dir /root/.node-gyp/4.2.6
gyp verb `which` succeeded for `make` /usr/bin/make
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'V=1', 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
make: Entering directory `/root/nodejs/napp1/node_modules/mynodemod/node_modules/mynodemod-protobuf/build'
  g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=protobuf_for_node' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DBUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION' -I/root/.node-gyp/4.2.6/include/node -I/root/.node-gyp/4.2.6/src -I/root/.node-gyp/4.2.6/deps/uv/include -I/root/.
node-gyp/4.2.6/deps/v8/include -I../../nan -I../sdk/protobuf/2.5.0/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -mminimal-toc -O3 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -s
td=gnu++0x -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/protobuf_for_node/protobuf_for_node.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/protobuf_for_node/protobuf_for_node.o ../protobuf_for_node.cc
  g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=protobuf_for_node' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DBUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION' -I/root/.node-gyp/4.2.6/include/node -I/root/.node-gyp/4.2.6/src -I/root/.node-gyp/4.2.6/deps/uv/include -I/root/.
node-gyp/4.2.6/deps/v8/include -I../../nan -I../sdk/protobuf/2.5.0/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -mminimal-toc -O3 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -s
td=gnu++0x -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/protobuf_for_node/addon.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/protobuf_for_node/addon.o ../addon.cc
  g++ -shared -pthread -rdynamic -m64  -Wl,-soname=protobuf_for_node.node -o Release/obj.target/protobuf_for_node.node -Wl,--start-group Release/obj.target/protobuf_for_node/protobuf_for_node.o Release/obj.target/protobuf_for_node/addon.o
 -Wl,--end-group ../sdk/protobuf/2.5.0/linux-x64/libprotobuf.a
/usr/bin/ld: ../sdk/protobuf/2.5.0/linux-x64/libprotobuf.a(descriptor.o): In function `void google::protobuf::STLDeleteContainerPointers<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<google::protobuf::FileDescriptorTables**, std::vector<google::protobuf::
FileDescriptorTables*, std::allocator<google::protobuf::FileDescriptorTables*> > > >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<google::protobuf::FileDescriptorTables**, std::vector<google::protobuf::FileDescriptorTables*, std::allocator<google::protob
uf::FileDescriptorTables*> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<google::protobuf::FileDescriptorTables**, std::vector<google::protobuf::FileDescriptorTables*, std::allocator<google::protobuf::FileDescriptorTables*> > >)':
(.text._ZN6google8protobuf26STLDeleteContainerPointersIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPPNS0_20FileDescriptorTablesESt6vectorIS5_SaIS5_EEEEEEvT_SB_[_ZN6google8protobuf26STLDeleteContainerPointersIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPPNS0_20File
DescriptorTablesESt6vectorIS5_SaIS5_EEEEEEvT_SB_]+0x44): call to `google::protobuf::FileDescriptorTables::~FileDescriptorTables()' lacks nop, can't restore toc; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Release/obj.target/protobuf_for_node.node] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/root/nodejs/napp1/node_modules/mynodemod/node_modules/mynodemod-protobuf/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/root/nodejs/napp1/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.10.0-229.ael7b.ppc64le
gyp ERR! command "/root/ibm/node/bin/node" "/root/nodejs/napp1/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp" "rebuild" "--verbose"
gyp ERR! cwd /root/nodejs/napp1/node_modules/mynodemod/node_modules/mynodemod-protobuf
gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.6
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.2.1
```

Comment: Edit your question to add the actual question mentioned in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Well I seem to have gotten it to compile... looked around at some seemingly unrelated posts and started wondering if the protobuf static libs that I'm linking in have to be compiled with -fPIC as well. Since I got the libs from the RPM, I went ahead and rebuilt them from source with fPIC. Now my node-gyp compiles fine...

Hopefully this will help someone else since I banged my head on this for a while...

Answer (score 0):

You might be hitting an inline assembly that calls an external function without adding a nop after it (for TOC restore).

The POWER ABI v2, at section **2.3.6. Function Calls**, says:

*Function calls need to be performed in conjunction with establishing, maintaining, and restoring addressability through the TOC pointer register, r2. When a function is called, the TOC pointer register may be modified. The caller must provide a nop after the bl instruction performing a call, if r2
is not known to have the same value in the callee. This is generally true for external calls. The linker will replace the nop with an r2 restoring instruction if the caller and callee use different r2 values, The linker leaves it unchanged if they use the same r2 value. This scheme avoids having a compiler generate an overconservative r2 save and restore around every external call.*